# Select multiple columns from one SQL

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, looker

This is the current code I have:

Code:

```
    SELECT
      type_code_1     AS unique_code,
      product_id      AS product_id,
      type_id         AS type_id,
      value           AS value,
    FROM
      Table1
    UNION
    SELECT
      type_code_2     AS unique_code,
      product_id      AS product_id,
      type_id         AS type_id,
      value           AS value,
    FROM
      Table2
    WHERE type_code_2 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT type_code_1 FROM Table1)
```

There are two tables that I am currently looking at, in order to extract one unique column for - unique_code and value.

This is now possible, however I need to be able to expand this code to have something like this:

```
    unique_code_1     value_1
    unique_code_2     value_2
    unique_code_3     value_3
    unique_code_4     value_4
    unique_code_5     value_5
```

I want to be able to select one column multiple times (by different name), so that I select different codes and their respective values.

In Looker these columns are used as dimensions, with simple drag and drop option and selecting from dropdown menu.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RUfJ.png)

Comment: From reading your question I am unsure exactly what you want, but my guess is you want to remove your WHERE entirely, and then also replace UNION with UNION ALL

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for replying. 
UNION should stay, as this is the current table I have, as value for unique code that I am using as dimension later, is coming from one of these two tables (that is why we have union and where condition).

I need to expand this table in order to have this unique code column appear  5 times, together with its value. 

So, if I filter on unique code in my Looker query, I should be able to assign different values to one column - thus I want to create multiple code-value pairs columns, with different names.

Comment: With the present query, you are already getting multiple `unique_code` and its `value`. I did not understand what exactly are you expecting ?

Comment: With this line * I need to expand this table in order to have this unique code column appear 5 times* you meant you want to repeat all `unique_code` 5 time each ?

Comment: End result should be: 

5 different columns for unique_code
5 different columns for value 

But all these 5 are coming from previously generated table using union and where. 
At the moment as a result I am getting only one column for unique_code and column for value from this derived table, and that's why I cannot query multiple code-value pairs at once.

Comment: Then you have to use `JOIN..ON` x 4 times with same query and wrap with basic `SELECT * FROM (...);` .

Comment: I cant exactly relate and understand your **COLUMNS** word with your question. You want 5 `unique_code` and 5 `values` side-by-side or one below the other ?

Comment: I want them as separate columns in the table. 
Imagine that you have just one column in the table, but you want to make another one using the same column, because you want to filter on multiple values. 
In SQL you can filter on values easily without making additional column, however in Looker, where I am trying to create this table, it is not possible. There you can filter on multiple values, only if you have that column appearing multiple times. And then for each code that you select, you should be also able to select value column (in most of the cases values for this one are true or false)

Comment: Please update your question with sample data for both tables and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Comment: I've added picture - see Example

Comment: Please don’t link to images as no-one can copy the data if they want to try a solution. Add all information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 1):

If you need 5 times the same column this will work

```
CREATE VIEW view_dropdown AS
(
SELECT type_code_1 AS unique_code,
       product_id  AS product_id,
       type_id     AS type_id,
       value       AS value,
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT type_code_2 AS unique_code,
       product_id  AS product_id,
       type_id     AS type_id,
       value       AS value,
FROM Table2
WHERE type_code_2 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT type_code_1 FROM Table1));

select A.unique_code,
       A.value,
       B.unique_code,
       B.value,
       C.unique_code,
       C.value,
       D.unique_code,
       D.value,
       E.unique_code,
       E.value
from view_dropdown A
         join view_dropdown B on A.unique_code = B.unique_code
         join view_dropdown C on A.unique_code = C.unique_code
         join view_dropdown D on A.unique_code = D.unique_code
         join view_dropdown E on A.unique_code = E.unique_code
```

Comment: I do have additional question. 
How I can show values in the initial table in case there are no records in the table? 

Example: 

Currently if I filter on the unique_code column, in case there are no values in the table, I won't see that in the output. What I would like to have is something like not configured and in value column the same. And that should work together with multiple values logic.